# Recursive Functions in Python vs C

Tags: python, c, recursion

It seems as if C allows for a function to reference itself (in a recursive manner) when executing, for example, the Collatz conjecture.

```c
int collatz(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int result = collatz(9);
    printf("Steps: %i\n", result);
}

int collatz(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;
    else if ((n % 2) == 0)
        return 1 + collatz(n / 2);
    else
        return 1 + collatz(3 * n + 1);
}
```

Python gives me an error when I try this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

when I reference the same function within itself:

```py
def collatz_recursive(n):

    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return 1 + collatz_recursive(n/2)
        else:
            return 1 + collatz_recursive(n * 3 + 1)
```

However, when I place `collatz` in its own function and reference it from the outside with `collatz_recursive` I don't have that problem:

```py
def collatz(n):
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n/2
        else:
            n = n * 3 + 1

def collatz_recursive(n):
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return 1 + collatz(n/2)
        else:
            return 1 + collatz(n * 3 + 1)
```

Comment: There's no loop in your C examples, why do you add it in python?

Comment: Python allows recursive functions, you're not telling the whole story. Or, maybe, you failed to reduce the story to a [mcve] first.

Comment: Did you notice that your C code doesn't use `while` at all? Your Python code fails not because of any Python language limitation, but because you messed up porting your code.

Comment: Your first Python function is lacking the `if n == 1` part of the C function

Comment: Your `collatz_recursive` sometimes returns None.

Comment: Works for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/TjxLVxz8o0jjDEly

Comment: first issue i see right of the bat is that the port isn't properly done, i recreated the issue and it seems you are adding nonetype during the supposedly recursion. means that somewhere, your code returns nonetype. It is caused by the issue that your python code did not have any base case unlike the C one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Python gives me an error when ... I reference the same function within itself"*

No, Python gives you an error because `collatz_recursive` doesn't return a value for `n == 1`. The return value of a function is `None` if no value was returned with a `return` statement.

Your Python code should look like

```py
def collatz_recursive(n):

    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 1 + collatz_recursive(n/2)
    else:
        return 1 + collatz_recursive(n * 3 + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The 'int' and 'NoneType' can not be added through + operation.

Here is my console for running your very last code:

```
 line 13, in collatz_recursive
    return 1 + collatz(n * 3 + 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I think the problem is that you forgot to handle the edge-case n=1 for your `collatz_recursive` function, you can easily log `n` by putting a print function before and after while loop and observe the bug.

Try to return a default value for your function, this is also named `base-case`.
You can read more about recursion and base case in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/)